# Failed to load plugin 'react' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app » ': Unexpected end of input

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I created a react project, and it has been working but it just started bringing up this error **Failed to load plugin 'react' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app » D:\Dev\fegig\omega\trade\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js': Unexpected end of input**,
i have tried re-saving my package.json file but it only fixed it temporarily

Please any ideas on how to fix this?
error image
[image]

Comment: please give us more examples of your code, package.json Webpack file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting the node module folder, and again install all of them, by running
npm install, or yarn, depending on the type of package manager you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are linting make sure your syntax is correct in your package.json file you may be missing a comma or something simple like that.